# FileManager removeItem() and getContent() issue

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, nsfilemanager, ios13

When I get the content of the following path `companies/foo` I only get `companies/foo/img` instead of `companies/foo/brokers`, `companies/foo/press articles` etc and then when I tried to delete the whole folder `companies/foo` the only folder deleted is `companies/foo/img`.

All the content inside brokers, press articles etc is available in the app. (mainly pdfs) so it really exists.

Lastly, if I tried to delete `companies/foo/brokers` directly I get the following error `couldn't removed` with no more info.

Any idea why 1) I can't get all the content inside my folder 2) I can't delete this content (excepted img)

Folder hierarchy :

```
Documents
  |_ companies
    |_ foo
      |_ brokers
      |_ press articles
      |_ img


static let documentsDirectory: URL? = {
     let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
     return url
}()


func eraseContent(at path: String) throws {
    do {
        guard let documentDirectory = FileSystem.documentsDirectory else {
            throw FilesError.documentDirectoryUnavailable
        }
        let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(path).path
        let path = url.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "")

        try manager.removeItem(atPath: path)
    } catch {
        Logger.error(path+" || "+error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you can't remove a folder because it isn't empty. So img is empty but the others aren't

Comment: @JoakimDanielson unfortunately the 'img' folder isn't empty at all, actually all the folder contains at least one file. And removeItem is supposed to remove recurcively the content inside the folder https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413590-removeitem